# MVC Autogenerated Index method - why is .include needed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC project and I've used EF to bring in the Products and Categories tables from the Northwind database. The Products table has a foreign-key constraint on CategoryID to the Categories table's CategoryID field. I used the wizard to add an MVC 5 controller with views, using EF. The Index action method has this code

```
// GET: Products
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var products = db.Products.Include(p => p.Category);
        return View(products.ToList());
    }
```

I assumed the .include was there to bring in the Category and allow the category name to be displayed in the view. But then I looked at the Details action method and it doesn't use this code even though it does display the category name. So then I tried stripping the .include out of the Index method to get this

```
var products = db.Products;
```

and ran it and I still get the category name displayed in the view. So now I'm confused as to why the .include code is in the Index action method but not in the Details method. Any input is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you know beforehand you're gonna need `Category` then it's best to `Include()` it so that EF will generate a more efficient SQL to retrieve it as well. When you don't use `Include()`, EF will run in "lazy-loading" mode and will issue another SQL when attempting to access `Category`. Obviously, lazy-loading will only work if enabled in configuration (it is, by default).

Answer (score 5):

`Include` has an impact on the underlying SQL query. When it is used, the query will do a join on the Category table, otherwise, the query will only load data from the Products table. If lazy loading is enabled (it is, by default), Category will be loaded from the database when the property is accessed.

From the application, this means you get exactly the same result. The difference is, with `Include`, only one query will be made, without it, you will have one query to retrieve the list of products, then one more every time you need to access the Category of a product for the first time. The performance impact can be significant (this is known as the N+1 problem, as to load a list of N items, you have to do N+1 round-trips to the database).

Comment: For an eagerly laoded query, you can set the lazy loading off with `objectContext.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up a bit. But I'm still not sure why .include is not in the Details method. Both the Details and the Index views need to display the CategoryName. Is it just a quirk that it's in one method and not the other or am I still missing something?

Comment: I guess it's simply because in the Details method, you probably load only 1 object, which means the performance impact of lazy loading is much smaller than on the index, where you load potentially hundreds of objects. To me, it looks like the code was written first without any `Include`, and later, when optimising, it was added where the performance impact was the greatest.